# multi-dimensional array indexing error in mono

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, mono

When i use mono 2.10.8.1 on debian to compile the code below, running it gives an `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` whilst compiling it in debuging mode doesn't, Further more it shouldn't give any errors. Is this a known bug?

```
using System;

namespace CompilerBug
{
    public class NotMain
    {
        public static void Main (string[] a)
        {
            bool[,] test = new bool[201,201];
            int x,y;
            for(x=-100;x<100;x++) for(y=-100;y<100;y++){
                test[x+100,y+100] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a `try` `catch` to print the indices for which it throws an exception? (BTW also you might want `x <= 100` and `y <= 100`.)

Comment: No, because when i add a `try` `catch` clause the code runs fine

Comment: _when i add a try catch clause the code runs fine_ - then at least you have a perfect workaround.

Comment: Sorry, but perfect and workaround shouldn't be in the same sentence, unless it would be in the lines of "In a perfect world workarounds aren't needed"

Comment: You have a neat and small test case, please file a bug with Mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apperently not a known bug, so reported it to mono.

Link to the bug report for further reference: [bugzilla.xamarin.com/...](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7438)